# Sublime text 3 refuses to load after executing infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

I am having a severe glitch after accidentally running an infinite loop in sublime text 3 with python.

I was forced to kill the program (force quit) as it became unresponsive. I subsequently tried to reopen Sublime Text 3, however the application became stuck once more in what I can only assume to be an infinite loop, even though I did not build the file again.

I am running Mac OS X version 10.9.5. I believe the problem may be with the fact that OS X reopens closed windows exactly to the state they were and this conflicts with IDEs, but even after unchecking the "Close open windows" option in System Preferences, ST3 remains broken. Any help? Because at this moment, ST3 is completely unusable for me.

Comment: Have you considered doing a complete uninstall and then reinstalling ST3?

Comment: I would like to avoid that as I have many packages installed and set up. Would there be a way to avoid the pain of reinstalling and setting up packages? I would be all for it then.

Comment: And you have rebooted the Mac already?

Comment: @duncan Yes I have rebooted already.

Comment: I believe this is more to do with sublime text rather than python (or programming). Flagging for migration to superuser.com

Comment: Did you kill the python process in the Activity Monitor?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to edit the session file and start removing references to the offending code and see if that helps.

On a mac it should be found here:
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/Session.sublime_session

This is just a guess, it might be in another file but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up deleting the Application Support file after saving the packages. It turned out to be something with Anaconda (a python plugin). Everything works now :)